# Momentjs not installing (npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

So I'm trying to install moment js (just a package) using npm but I keep getting this error:

```
npm i moment --save
```

---

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/runner/Movies/movie-reviews/frontend/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin
npm ERR! dest /home/runner/Movies/movie-reviews/frontend/node_modules/.case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin-PTFkDx5w
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/runner/Movies/movie-reviews/frontend/node_modules/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin' -> '/home/runner/Movies/movie-reviews/frontend/node_modules/.case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin-PTFkDx5w'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T21_20_05_137Z-debug-0.log`
```

It also isn't installing momentjs. I tried deleting the files fron the directory not empty error and it instead showed me files from another package I installed. What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried entirely deleting the `node_modules` directory?

Comment: @Phil It has a bunch of modules I need and modules from react so I wouldn't want to

Comment: It's ok to delete it. You simply run `npm install` again and everything will come back, hopefully without issues